Is there a way to update UI automatically with Docker Desktop?
I have installed Docker Desktop and using WSL 2 and I am practicing in a front-end project. Every time that I want to see a change in the UI (for instance, change a h2 tag or add an extra div), I have to use
docker compose down

docker rmi image_id

and then again
docker compose up

But this is taking so much of my time and I was wondering if there is something that I could do to make it so that I can instantly see any change in my code, in the UI.
I've searched and found that I can edit the docker-compose.yml and add the line
volumes:
      - .:/app

but it didn't work.
I found, also, this video, used the command, no success still.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Docker's core model is that the container filesystem is isolated from the host filesystem, and that containers generally run on an immutable copy of the application code that needs to be rebuilt.  If you want a live development environment, you may find it much easier to use Node and other similar tools directly on your host system, without involving Docker at all.

@DavidMaze I understand. I was told I could do it with Docker. But I will find other tools to help me. Thank you!

You want to use Docker compose watch
Without using volume mounts, it syncs files into a running container and can trigger build commands as necessary.
Nodemon also can streamline triggering a rebuild on file changes.
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    develop:
      watch:
      - action: sync
        path: ./
        target: /app/
        ignore:
          - node_modules/
      - action: rebuild
        path: package.json


Thank you for your answer. I've adjusted the paths. It pops an error docker-entrypoint.sh: 47: exec: npm: not found. Is it possible that Node.js isn't installed?
Or maybe I messed up the paths?

The example I showed demonstrated the workflow if you are doing node/npm development for your frontend. In this case, your Dockerfile should start with "FROM node:..." or an image that contains tools like npm and node.

My Dockerfile does start with "FROM node: 16.13.1-slim as react build".

node:16.13.1-slim definitely contains npm. The most common reason for "not found" errors on Windows systems are files that are CRLF rather than just LF but Its hard to tell where or why that might be so.

I am in Windows system, but i run WSL with ubuntu. Also, is it possible that the problem is at my docker-compose.yml file? Paths wrong, or something similar? In addition, my dockerfile has two stages.
First stage: FROM node...
Second stage: From nginx.

it could be but this deserves its own whole question.

I will open a new question then.  Thanks.
